# Python Regex: Check for match and capture groups

Tags: python, regex, if-statement

I want to ensure that a string matches a regular expression using an if statement, and store capture groups simultaneously. I think the following code shows what I want, but it is syntactically invalid. Is there a way to achieve the following elegantly?

```
yyyyq_format = "19984"

if regex_match = re.search("^(\d{4})(\d)$", yyyyq_format):
    found_q = regex_match[2]
else:
    raise ValueError("Format \"yyyyq\" is not followed.")
```

I know the following works (is this my only option?):

```
yyyyq_format = "19984"
regex_match = re.search("^(\d{4})(\d)$", yyyyq_format)

if regex_match:
    found_q = regex_match[2]
else:
    raise ValueError("Format \"yyyyq\" is not followed.")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PEP-572  (assignment expressions)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) implemeted what is being called the *walrus operator* that you can use to evaluate an expression and assign the return to a name in one go e.g.:

```
if regex_match := re.search("^(\d{4})(\d)$", yyyyq_format):
    found_q = regex_match[2]
else:
    raise ValueError("Format \"yyyyq\" is not followed.")
```

Note the `:` before `=`.

This is (will be) available in Python 3.8.

Before that, your second option is the only way I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Walrus operator `:=` in Python 3.8 is one option, or you can do `for else` statement (note the `re.finditer`):

```
import re

yyyyq_format = "19984"

for g in re.finditer("^(\d{4})(\d)$", yyyyq_format):
    found_q = g[2]
    break
else:
    raise ValueError("Format \"yyyyq\" is not followed.")

print(found_q)
```

Prints:

```
4
```

Comment: This is pretty expensive just to check for match.

Comment: @heemayl Why expensive? OP wanted to have assign the second group to `found_q` or raise exception.

Comment: Well, for starter whats the point of a `for` loop when you can easily get the desired match by `match(2)` and jsut checking against `None` gets you if there is even a match. It's trivial and Pythonic.

Comment: @heemayl the point is that OP didn't want to make temporary variable (`regex_match`) outside.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this expensive at all, and actually does exactly what I want. There is guaranteed 1 iteration maximum, with 0 iterations as the lower bound